# How to get location lat and long from json in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, jsonparser

I am retrieve value latitude and longitude from JSON in flutter.I try many thing but not git value of lat and long
this is my json file

> {
> "results": [
> {
> "geometry": {
> "location": {
> "lat": 19.2058593,
> "lng": 72.86612
> }
> }
> }
> ] }

I try

```
>  var myMap = json.decode(data.toString());
>       var myName = myMap['results']['geometry']['location']['lat']
```

but not getting location values.please help me in flutter

Answer (score 3):

Change it to :

```
 myName = myMap['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
```

This is because `"geometry"` is inside a list. It's at `index[0]` of this list, after accessing `"results"`.